# setkomafont LARGE causes non-termination

Tags: koma-script

I want to increase the size of the font in the part entry for a toc - using KOMA scrbook.
When I add `LARGE` to the `setkomafont` command, the compilation does not terminate anymore. Why? what is the proper way to set the font size in the toc?

related question: why does the `setkomafont{disposition}` command clash with a specific setting later?

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
    \KOMAoptions{paper=      
        128.5mm:198.4mm, %(5,06" x 7,91")  %ziel
        DIV=9,  %ziel kleines buch 
        fontsize=12pt,
    }

%%%% Sprache
\usepackage[german]{babel}  %scheint 

%%%% table of content
\setcounter{tocdepth}{0} %   1 gibt parts und chapter und sections

%%% schrift fuer alle eintraege
%\setkomafont{disposition}{\rmfamily\normalcolor}
%conflict with specific settings 

%
%%for table of content
\setkomafont{partentry}{\mdseries\scshape\lowercase\LARGE} %\LARGE loop
\setkomafont{chapterentry}{\mdseries\scshape\lowercase}
%

\usepackage{fontspec}

%%%%% FONTS 
\newfontfamily{\titlefont}{CormorantGaramond}   %for the titles



\begin{document}
    \frontmatter
        \tableofcontents

    \mainmatter

\part{ Philosophie}
\chapter{  \textit{Vom Schreiben}}

Man spricht davon, dass es heute schwierig sei zu schreiben. 

\end{document}
```

Comment: I just get an error, with or without `\LARGE`.

Comment: Remove the \lowercase.

Comment: `\lowercase` is not a font changing command.